# Cockcroft walton multiplier output both AC and DC?

Tags: voltage, power-electronics, electromagnetism, high-voltage, multiplier

I was watching this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ep3D_LC2UzU
and I noticed that closer to the end he is probing the upper half of the circuit and the scope is displaying square waves , also on the lower side his diagram shows one can take off DC. 
start about 14 min in the video you can see it on the board.

Also a separate question, can a CW multiplier be used to step up voltage pulses where one would input a lower voltage pulse and get out a higher one?
Or do the capacitors in the circuit spread out the pulse and flatten its steep rise time?

Answer (score 2):

The output of a Cockroft-Walton generator is DC and it takes a while (many cycles) to build up.

See [this](https://scholarworks.uark.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1065&context=eleguht) undergrad thesis, for example:

[image]

If you want to generate really high voltage pulses,  you can use a [Marx generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marx_generator).

Answer (score 1):

A CW multiplier is used (along with a power oscillator) to step-up a DC voltage from a lower voltage to a higher voltage. It produces DC on its "normal" output but on each stage there will be a pulsing waveform superimposed on the previous stage's DC output.

The pulse remains the same amplitude throughout all the stages except for accumulated diode drops and therefore, it has a tendency to become slightly smaller in amplitude as it passes from stage to stage.

[image]

Picture from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cockcroft_Walton_voltage_multiplier_circuit.svg).

> *can a CW multiplier be used to step up voltage pulses where one would
>   input a lower voltage pulse and get out a higher one?*

No. [Dave has the explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ep3D_LC2UzU).

Comment: Er, maybe you meant step up an *AC* voltage? And a Marx generator can make pulses.

Comment: @hacktastical is that comment meant for me?

Comment: Yes. A CW multiplier needs AC input to do its thing.

Comment: Ok I see your point.